# Are all local martingales continuous in probability?

Tags: continuity, stochastic-processes, martingales, local-martingales

We say $X$ is  *continuous in probability* if for any      $t_0 \geqslant 0$ fixed, we have     $ \mathbb{P}\left(\left\|X_{t}-X_{t_0}\right\|>\varepsilon\right) \rightarrow 0$     as $t \rightarrow t_0$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. This is also known as *stochastically continuous.*

When $X$ is also cadlag, it follows that $X$ cannot have fixed discontinuities. As far as I know, a martingale cannot have a fixed discontinituity and its jumps are at random times. Is there a martingale which is **not** continuous in probability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a martingale can have a fixed discontinuity.  For example, let $Z \in \mathcal F_1$ be a Bernoulli random variable independent of $\mathcal F_{1^-}$ with $P(Z=1)=P(Z=-1)=\frac 12$.  Then $X_t := Z 1_{t \ge 1}$ is a martingale that is constant at $0$ before $1$, then jumps to $\pm 1$ at time $1$.  This martingale is not continuous in probability.

Comment: A beautiful counterexample, thanks!